# I want to show node value in extjs 4 line chart

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

When we take mouse on line chart node then it is showing nodes values. Same thing i want to permanently without pointing to node.

My complete code is:

```
items:[{
    xtype:'displayfield', 
    value:'Avg. Freight Percentage'
},{ 
    xtype: 'linechart', 
    store: store30DaysTo180Days,
    xField: 'days',
    height:200,
    yField: 'averageFreightPercentLast', 
    xAxis: new Ext.chart.CategoryAxis({ title: 'In Days', })
}]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example ? Here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/charts/Line.html the values are not showing on the nodes.

Comment: The link you provided is showing nodes, that node will have some X and Y value. I want to show X and Y value on that node.

Comment: Please Check mentioned url http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/extjs-build/examples/charts/Charts.html

Answer (score 1):

The config `label` is for this purpose. Try something like:

```
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    axis: 'left',
    markerConfig: {
        type: 'cross'
    },
    highlight: true,
    label: {
        display: 'inside', // or 'rotate'
        field: 'revenue',
        'text-anchor': 'start'
// I found that undocumented property with values 'start', 'end' or 'middle'
    },
    tips: {
        trackMouse: true,
        width: 80,
        height: 25,
        renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
            this.setTitle(item.value[1] + ' $</span>');
        }
    },
    xField: 'month',
    yField: 'revenue'
}]
```

For more information look at [the docs for label](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Line-cfg-label).

Unfortunately, there are only few possibilities to style it. To get something good, you need to use the `renderer` function (this one really allows you to do all you can think of for a label).

Comment: Sorry for wrong version of extjs. I am using extjs version 3.1. My required graph is like image attached in given url https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4127135/graph.png.

Comment: This really works with the `label` property. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for wrong version of extjs. I am using extjs version 3.1. My required graph is like  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4127135/graph.png.

I am able to create like https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4127135/mygaph.png.
My complete code is
<pre><code>
items:[{
      xtype:'displayfield',
      value:'Avg. Freight Percentage',
     },{
 xtype: 'linechart',
 store: store30DaysTo180Days,
 xField: 'days',
 height:200,
 yField: 'averageFreightPercentLast',
 xAxis: new Ext.chart.CategoryAxis({
    title: 'In Days',
 })
}]
</pre></code>